# Как подписаться на Bot_OnCallbackQuery? Telegram.Bot api c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telegram-bot, telegram

разбираюсь с работой Telegram Bot, понадобилось создать кнопки, но не могу понять как подписаться на событие нажатия inline кнопки в цикле. Выдаёт ошибку:  Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

```csharp
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {

            MainLoop().Wait();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR - " + ex);
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
        }
    }
}

static async Task MainLoop()
{

    // Начало работы
    var bot = new TelegramBotClient("-----");
    var me = await bot.GetMeAsync();
    bot.SetWebhookAsync("");
    Console.WriteLine(me.Username + "Начало: " + DateTime.Now);


    var offset = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var updates = new Update[0];
        try
        {
            updates = await bot.GetUpdatesAsync(offset);

        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            // 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при получени обновления - " + ex);
        }
        foreach (var update in updates)
        {

            offset = update.Id + 1;
            ProcessUpdateAsync(bot, update, me);
        }

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}


static async Task ProcessUpdateAsync(TelegramBotClient bot, Update update, Telegram.Bot.Types.User me)
{
    // обработка запросов

    try
    {

        var text = update.Message.Text; //тут ошибка

        var replyText = string.Empty;
        var replyTextMarkdown = string.Empty;

        if (text != null && (text.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) || text.StartsWith("!", StringComparison.Ordinal)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(update.Message.Chat.Id + " < " + update.Message.From.Username + " - " + text);

            // Разрешен ! или /
            if (text.StartsWith("!", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                text = "/" + text.Substring(1);
            }
        }

        // Полоса @BotName
        text = text.Replace("@" + me.Username, "");

        // Parse
        string command;
        string body;
        if (text.StartsWith("/s/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            command = "/s";
            body = text.Substring(2);
        }
        else
        {
            command = text.Split(' ')[0];
            body = text.Replace(command, "").Trim();
        }
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня такое было. Eсли сообщение, содержащееся в обновлении от другого бота, то добавил проверку на `null`, но по сути я просто стал пропускать сообщения других ботов. Так получается из-за того, что боты не видят сообщения других ботов.

+где строка типа:

```
bot.OnCallBackQuery += *обработчик*;
```

?